# What does $$ mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
Process.kill :HUP, $$
```

What does the `$$` mean here? I think it's the child process' PID, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

`$$` is the process id (`PID`). Find a list of all `$` in [Ruby 's `English.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/English.rb)